# Magento 2: Admin Panel Error in Processing request

Tags: magento2, admin, theme

I was following the instructions on MageStore to create a new theme. I created **frontend > cbg > SimpleTheme** and in that I have the theme.xml as follows

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
```

SimpleTheme 
        
         media/preview.jpg

And I created a registration as follows

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
        'frontend/cbg/SimpleTheme',
        __DIR__
    );
```

Also I created the etc with the view.xml as copied from another theme (solwin freego).

Now the front ed is still there but I cannot access the admin area.

Comment: It was as simple as changing the preview file name from .jpg to .png since thats what I had. Crashed the whole admin area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Theme.xml preview was set to the incorrect file name. I had the extension of jpg when the extension in the server was .png. Even though its not a true preview, the names must be correct or the admin section crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an image file extension issue, maybe media folder missing in your theme.
So please create one media folder within app/design/frontend/Cbg/SimpleTheme directory. And add preview.jpg file in it.

One more thing make sure your theme vendor folder name should be "Cbg" and theme folder name should be "SimpleTheme"